# Python Error: “ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack”

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to learn how to code in Python, whenever I do a exercise involving `from sys import argv` I get this error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Kaleb/PycharmProjects/python ex13.py", line 3, in 
>       script, first, second, third = argv ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

This is the code im trying to do:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

I am not sure why it is doing this and im very new to coding. I had had a look around but I cannot find anything helpful or that I can understand.

What does this error mean and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Did you run the script with three additional arguments?

Comment: Nope that is the whole code.

Comment: I asked how you _run the script_, as in, `C:\Users\Kaleb> py myscript.py 1 2 3`.

Comment: Nope sorry I am very new to coding

Comment: What do you mean, "nope"? You didn't pass three arguments? Can you tell us how you _did_ run it, then? The exercise should have discussed this; it's kind of the whole point of it.

Comment: Do you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: No I do not underesatand sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Error: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814128/python-error-valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack)

Comment: If you don't even understand the troubleshooting questions, that means you should actually read the exercises, not just copy and paste the code into a .py file.

Comment: My problem was i was not calling the script correctly thanks if you helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly fine if you call it correctly. Assuming you script is called `output.py` you need to run it like this:

```
python output.py z u i
```

where `z`, `u` and `i` are three arguments which you try to unpack. Then you receive:

```
The script is called: output.py
Your first variable is: z
Your second variable is: u
Your third variable is: i
```

If you call it without these three arguments just using

```
python output.py
```

you receive the error message you mentioned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "output.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign variables to non-existent values

```
script, first, second, third = argv
```

When you call your script you need to pass in three parameters as well

So you can call your script like this:

```
python ex13.py test1 test2 test3
```

You should see:

```
The script is called: ./ex13.py                                                                            
Your first variable is: test1                                                                               
Your second variable is: test2                                                                              
Your third variable is: test3
```